# -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender not geting called

Tags: iphone, xcode, methods, storyboard, call

I am working on Storyboards.I have used a table view and on its cell i have created a Segue from this table view cell prototype to a new view controller.

also i have included a method

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    UITableViewCell *cell=sender;
    NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);
    thirdViewController *thid=[segue destinationViewController];
    thid.strValue=cell.textLabel.text;

}
```

but it is not getting called.

When does this method get called..?

Any help will be Appreciated.

Thanks
Vikas

Comment: Where is that method? Does the segue still happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open new Viewcontroller then try with below line hope it helps you:

```
       UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
       Synergy *objSynergy = (Synergy *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Synergy"];
      [self presentModalViewController:objSynergy animated:YES];
```

Synergy is my new controller name you replace it with your class name change this code according to your requirement.